# JAXB: simplify xsd before generating the Java classes (choice with one element)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I would like to generate Java classes from an XML schema (XSD) using JAXB.

An extract of the XML is as follow:

```
<xs:complexType name="IfcArbitraryClosedProfileDef">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ifc:IfcProfileDef">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="OuterCurve">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:element ref="ifc:IfcCurve">
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I don't know much about XML schema however I believe that an element choice with one element only is equivalent to putting the element without surrounding it with the choice element.

```
<xs:complexType name="IfcArbitraryClosedProfileDef">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ifc:IfcProfileDef">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="OuterCurve" type="ifc:IfcCurve" nillable="true"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

**Problem**
JAXB generates a class `OuterCurve` that holds one attribute of type `IfcCurve` class: (`OuterCurve` is a wrapper to `IfcCurve`)

**What I would like**

- I would like to remove the class OuterCurve and use the class
  IfcCureve directly.

**Constraints**

- I have many definition similar to this one (I would like to automate
  the process)
- I don't want to modify the XSD directly.

**Questions**

- Is there a solution that uses JAXB bindings?
- Is there an XJC plugin that does this?
- If I would like to develop the XJC plugin myself. Do you have any
  suggestions on how to do it?
- Is there a way to do this using XSL and how can I do it?

I am open to any other suggestions you may have.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Good question - all the information is there. You may want to proceed with caution - some of those single-option choices might acquire other options in future, and then you code structure will need to change.

Comment: The XSD file is related to an ISO standard. I am pretty sure it will take time to change it and if they change it they will implement a new version of it